# Is it possible to force EULA during Android app installation?

Tags: android, google-play

While uploading an Android application to Google Playstore, I didn't see any option to specify EULA text. I am wondering if it is possible to enforce EULA such that a user has to agree to it before the install can happen.

If this is not possible, I would need to programmatically force the user to agree on first use.

Answer (score 2):

I had to handle this recently. I never could figure out how to integrate our EULA with the Google Play Store, so I settled for a solution involving showing the EULA on first use. I had an additional constraint in that I had to re-show the EULA with every app update.

This was the basic overview of my approach:

- Use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/intl/ko/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) to store the current app version EULA that had been accepted.
- Compare current app version on startup against the one in SharedPreferences
- If they don't match, display a custom DialogFragment with a Webview that I would display the EULA in(since mine was an html file). I configured the DialogFragment to be modal. i.e. only have an Accept button and to not be dismissed if they touched outside.
- Update the current app version in SharedPreferences once accepted.